# Lucene IndexReader upgrade

Tags: java, lucene, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade Lucene in my application  from version 3.5.0 to 5.0.0. The application has this code:

```
IndexReader indexReader=IndexReader.open(index);
String[] fields = indexReader.getFieldNames(FieldOption.ALL).toArray(new String[0]);
```

I need the fieldNames so I use them in a  MultiFieldQueryParser. How can I make the change to version 5.0.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get field information from the reader using the [`LeafReader.getFieldInfos()`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/LeafReader.html#getFieldInfos()) method, and in turn, you can get the field name from `FieldInfo.name`:

```
public static String[] getFieldNames(IndexReader reader) {
    List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    //For a simple reader over only one index, reader.leaves() should only  return one LeafReaderContext
    for (LeafReaderContext readerCtx : reader.leaves()) {
        FieldInfos fields = readerCtx.reader().getFieldInfos();
        for (FieldInfo field : fields) {
            //Check whether the field is indexed and searchable, perhaps?
            fieldNames.add(field.name);
        }
    }
    return fieldNames.toArray(new String[fieldNames.size()]); 
}
```

---

Note:  It might worth considering using a catch-all field that contains all the content you want to search for, instead.  This is a common, and quite useful, pattern (e.g. Elasticsearch does this by default, with their [_all field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/mapping-all-field.html))

Going that route, you can expect the index to become a bit larger, but it makes it simpler to use, and performance should be improved.